Trying to use PersistedAssemblyBuilder to build an exe but I get errors when i try to run it
I'm trying to build a simple app to learn about creating .net exes to eventually use in a compiler. I'm using .net 9 rc2, and tried copying code from the samples:
public static void BuildExe()
{
    try
    {
        PersistedAssemblyBuilder ab = AssemblySaveTools.PopulateAssemblyBuilder(_assemblyName);
        TypeBuilder tb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("MyModule").DefineType("MyType", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class);
        MethodBuilder mb1 = tb.DefineMethod("SumMethod", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(int), [typeof(int), typeof(int)]);
        ILGenerator il = mb1.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        MethodBuilder entryPoint = tb.DefineMethod("Main", MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(int), null);
        ILGenerator il2 = entryPoint.GetILGenerator();
        il2.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, 10);
        il2.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2);
        il2.Emit(OpCodes.Call, mb1);
        il2.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        tb.CreateType();

        MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder = ab.GenerateMetadata(out BlobBuilder ilStream, out BlobBuilder fieldData);
        PEHeaderBuilder peHeaderBuilder = new PEHeaderBuilder(
                        imageCharacteristics: Characteristics.ExecutableImage,
                        subsystem: Subsystem.WindowsCui);

        ManagedPEBuilder peBuilder = new ManagedPEBuilder(
                        header: peHeaderBuilder,
                        metadataRootBuilder: new MetadataRootBuilder(metadataBuilder),
                        ilStream: ilStream,
                        mappedFieldData: fieldData,
                        entryPoint: MetadataTokens.MethodDefinitionHandle(entryPoint.MetadataToken));

        BlobBuilder peBlob = new BlobBuilder();
        peBuilder.Serialize(peBlob);

        // in case saving to a file:
        //using var stream = new MemoryStream();
        using var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\mine.exe", FileMode.Create);
        peBlob.WriteContentTo(stream);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

When I try to run it directly (myassembly2.exe), I get:

Failed to run as a self-contained app.

The application was run as a self-contained app because 'C:\temp\myassembly2.runtimeconfig.json' was not found.
If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the 'C:\temp\myassembly2.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify the appropriate framework.


When I try to run it using the dotnet command I get:

A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\temp'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app.

The application was run as a self-contained app because 'C:\temp\myassembly2.runtimeconfig.json' was not found.
If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the 'C:\temp\myassembly2.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify the appropriate framework.


Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks!
